# How to save KEGG pathways as variables in Rmarkdown for self reporting?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to display KEGG pathways in an R markdown, but they are all saved as pngs. I am able to display them in the report, but I have to add the name of each file, which makes it harder to update the file if the code is changed. Does anyone know how I can save the png file generated by the code below so I can have the rmarkdown file update the image whenever the code or data changes? I've added the code and the website where I found it and the data below.

https://rpubs.com/barryus/class15

---

### title: "kegg"
output: html_document
date: "2023-02-07"

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
#link to source code and data: https://rpubs.com/barryus/class15
```

```
#BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
library(DESeq2)
#BiocManager::install("AnnotationDbi")
library("AnnotationDbi")
#BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")
library("org.Hs.eg.db")
#BiocManager::install("pathview")
library(pathview)
#BiocManager::install("gage")
library(gage)
#BiocManager::install("gageData")
library(gageData)


#import source data
metaFile <- "GSE37704_metadata.csv"
countFile <- "GSE37704_featurecounts.csv"

# Import metadata and take a peak
colData = read.csv(metaFile, row.names=1)
head(colData)

# Import countdata
countData = read.csv(countFile, row.names=1)
head(countData)

# Note we need to remove the odd first $length col
#   need the countData and colData files to match up so we will need to
#   remove that odd first column in countData namely contData$length.
countData <- as.matrix(countData[,-1])
head(countData)

# Filter count data where you have 0 read count across all samples.
countData = countData[rowSums(countData)>1, ]
head(countData)

#setup the DESeqDataSet object required for the DESeq() function
tdds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=countData,
                              colData=colData,
                              design=~condition)

#run the DESeq pipeline
tdds = DESeq(tdds)
tdds

#get results for the HoxA1 knockdown versus control siRNA
#   labeled these as “hoxa1_kd” and “control_sirna” in our original colData metaFile input to DESeq
tres = results(tdds, contrast=c("condition", "hoxa1_kd", "control_sirna"))

#check names
resultsNames(tdds)

#reorder these results by p-value and call summary() on the results object
#   gives you a sense of how many genes are up or down-regulated at the default FDR of 0.1
#   FDR: "false-discovery rate" is the fraction of positives that are false positives at a given p-value threshold
tres = tres[order(tres$pvalue),]
summary(tres)

#Since we mapped and counted against the Ensembl annotation, our results only have information about Ensembl gene IDs
#   However, our pathway analysis downstream will use KEGG pathways
#   genes in KEGG pathways are annotated with Entrez gene IDs
#   need to add Entrez IDs
columns(org.Hs.eg.db)

tres$symbol = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db,
                     keys=row.names(tres),
                     column="SYMBOL",
                     keytype="ENSEMBL",
                     multiVals="first")

tres$entrez = mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db,
                     keys=row.names(tres),
                     column="ENTREZID",
                     keytype="ENSEMBL",
                     multiVals="first")

tres$name =   mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db,
                     keys=row.names(tres),
                     column="GENENAME",
                     keytype="ENSEMBL",
                     multiVals="first")

head(tres, 10)

#use the gage package for pathway analysis.
#Once we have a list of enriched pathways
#    use the pathview package to draw pathway diagrams
#    shading the molecules in the pathway by their degree of up/down-regulation.

# gageData package has pre-compiled databases mapping genes to KEGG pathways and GO terms for common organisms
#     kegg.sets.hs is a named list of 229 elements.
#     Each element is a character vector of member gene Entrez IDs for a single KEGG pathway. (See also go.sets.hs)
#     The sigmet.idx.hs is an index of numbers of signaling and metabolic pathways in kegg.set.gs
#     KEGG pathway include other types of pathway definitions which may be undesirable in pathway analysis
#         i.e: “Global Map” and “Human Diseases”

#setup the KEGG data-sets we need.
data(kegg.sets.hs)
data(sigmet.idx.hs)

kegg.sets.hs = kegg.sets.hs[sigmet.idx.hs]
head(kegg.sets.hs, 3)

#main gage() function requires a named vector of fold changes, where the names of the values are the Entrez gene IDs.
tfoldchanges = tres$log2FoldChange
names(tfoldchanges) = tres$entrez
head(tfoldchanges)

# run the pathway analysis
#     might want to try changing the value of same.dir.
#     This value determines whether to test for
#         a. changes in a gene set toward a single direction (all genes up or down regulated)
#         b. changes towards both directions simultaneously (i.e. any genes in the pathway dysregulated).
#     we’re using same.dir=TRUE, which will give us separate lists for pathways that are upregulated-
#     versus pathways that are down-regulated. Let’s look at the first few results from each.

#Get the results for the pathway analysis
keggtres = gage(tfoldchanges, gsets=kegg.sets.hs, same.dir=TRUE)

#look at the result object
#   It is a list with three elements (“greater”, “less” and “stats”).
attributes(keggtres)

#keggtres is a list object
class(keggtres) #[1] "list"

#use the dollar syntax to access a named element, e.g.
head(keggtres$greater)
head(keggtres$less)


#look at both up (greater), down (less), and statistics by calling head() with the lapply() function.
#   both keggtres$greater and keggtres$less are data matrices with gene sets as rows sorted by p-value.
lapply(keggtres, head)

#process the results to pull out the top 5 upregulated pathways
#   further process that just to get the IDs
#   use these KEGG pathway IDs downstream for plotting

## Sanity check displaying all pathways data
tpathways = data.frame(id=rownames(keggtres$greater), keggtres$greater)
head(tpathways)

#use the pathview() function to make a pathway plot with our result shown in color.
#   manually supply a pathway.id (namely the first part of the "hsa04110 Cell cycle")
#   this is visible from the print out above.
# code blw downloads the patway figure data from KEGG and adds our results to it

pathview(gene.data=tfoldchanges, pathway.id="hsa04110") #svrl gns r perturbed (the coloured ones)

# A different PDF based output of the same data
#there are df arrows on this one
pathview(gene.data=tfoldchanges, pathway.id="hsa04110", kegg.native=FALSE)

#process our results a bit more to automagicaly pull out the top 5 upregulated pathways
#   then further process that just to get the IDs needed by the pathview() function
#   We’ll use these KEGG pathway IDs for plotting below.

## Focus on top 5 upregulated pathways here for demo purposes only
keggtrespathways <- rownames(keggtres$greater)[1:5]

# Extract the IDs part of each string
keggtresids = substr(keggtrespathways, start=1, stop=8)
keggtresids

#pass these IDs in keggtresids to the pathview() function to draw plots for all the top 5 pathways.
pathview(gene.data=tfoldchanges, pathway.id=keggtresids, species="hsa")
```

**IMAGE**

```
#may need to change image name 
knitr::include_graphics("hsa04060.pathview.png", error = FALSE)
```

Comment: This might be a bit too complex for an SO question, but it intrigue's me and I will see if it makes sense given the code and background web citation.

Comment: Sadly, after running the installation of packages (which does take more than the 5 minutes alotted to revising comments) I now see `#import source data;
metaFile <- "GSE37704_metadata.csv"; 
countFile <- "GSE37704_featurecounts.csv"` and am realizing that these are almost certainly not avaialble and confirming this with "cannot open file 'GSE37704_metadata.csv': No such file or directory". So voting (with regret) to close.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I just double checked and both files used are on downloadable from the website link attached (https://rpubs.com/barryus/class15)

Comment: That was not in the least obvious from your question.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was to save the pathview function as a variable. It is a list, so I just used the names(pathview variable) with paste to attach it to either .png or .pathview.png